# With AWS Rekognition APIs, how to detect emotions in a video?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-rekognition

I am novice in this and doing this just for fun, i see detect-faces api which can return emotion, age and gender details. But not able to get a similar feature for video related APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to obtain such information from a video stored in Amazon S3:

- Call [StartFaceDetection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_StartFaceDetection.html) to start processing the video
- When it is finished, call [GetFaceDetection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_GetFaceDetection.html) to retrieve the results

The response includes emotion, age and gender:

```
{
   "Faces": [ 
      { 
         "Face": { 
            "AgeRange": { 
               "High": number,
               "Low": number
            },
            "Beard": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": boolean
            },
            "BoundingBox": { 
               "Height": number,
               "Left": number,
               "Top": number,
               "Width": number
            },
            "Confidence": number,
            "Emotions": [ 
               { 
                  "Confidence": number,
                  "Type": "string"
               }
            ],
            "Eyeglasses": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": boolean
            },
            "EyesOpen": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": boolean
            },
            "Gender": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": "string"
            },
            "Landmarks": [ 
               { 
                  "Type": "string",
                  "X": number,
                  "Y": number
               }
            ],
            "MouthOpen": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": boolean
            },
            "Mustache": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": boolean
            },
            "Pose": { 
               "Pitch": number,
               "Roll": number,
               "Yaw": number
            },
            "Quality": { 
               "Brightness": number,
               "Sharpness": number
            },
            "Smile": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": boolean
            },
            "Sunglasses": { 
               "Confidence": number,
               "Value": boolean
            }
         },
         "Timestamp": number
      }
   ],
   "JobStatus": "string",
   "NextToken": "string",
   "StatusMessage": "string",
   "VideoMetadata": { 
      "Codec": "string",
      "DurationMillis": number,
      "Format": "string",
      "FrameHeight": number,
      "FrameRate": number,
      "FrameWidth": number
   }
}
```